# Trimming an int array for bucket sort in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am writing a bucket sort program in C.  After I merge small buckets into a large bucket, I need to remove the -1s I padded the small buckets with.

I'm pretty new to C, so there could be a very simple solution that I am overlooking.

This was my solution, which seems to return an array with 1 trailing junk value and trailing 0s that fill the array until it is the size of the untrimmed bucket (where the desired result is a bucket without -1s, junk values, and trailing 0s).

```
    // A function to trim a bucket of a given size to a bucket containing no -1s
    int* trimBucket(int* bucket, int size)
    {
        int n = 0, i = 0;
        int* newBucket;

        // This loop is to count the number of elements between 0 and 9999
        for(n = 0; n < size; n++) 
        {
            if(bucket[n] != -1 && bucket[n] < 10000)
                i++;
        }

        // Create a new bucket equal to the number of elements counted
        // Filled with -2 to differentiate from -1s contained in the bucket array
        newBucket = allocateAndInitiateOneD(i, -2); 
        i = 0;

        for(n = 0; n < size; n++)
        {
            // I only want values between 0-9999 to be put into the new array
            if(bucket[n] != -1 && bucket[n] < 10000) 
            {
                newBucket[i] = bucket[n];
                i++;
            }       
        }

        free(bucket); // Am I doing this right?
        return newBucket;
    }
```

allocateAndInitiateOneD function:

```
    // A function to allocate memory for a one dimensional array and fill it with the given value
    int* allocateAndInitiateOneD(int x, int initialNum)
    {
        int runs = 0;
        int* oneArray;

        oneArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * x);

        for(runs = 0; runs < x; runs++)
            oneArray[runs] = initialNum;

        return oneArray;
    }
```

Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how I could get the desired result?

Thanks for the help!

edit:  I am compiling and running on a Unix system.  Possibly not related, but this is a multi-processed program using the MPI library (this doesn't seem to be where the problem lies).

Comment: The program is homework.  Was I supposed to tag that?  The assignment is to write a bucket sort that uses n processes, with each process containing n buckets.  My inexperience with C, specifically with arrays in C, isn't really the assigned problem...

Comment: Yeah, or at least mention, so we can guide, rather than solve. I don't know if I have enough rep to add tags or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like everything is working, but you need to return the new size from this function as well, without the idea of the length of the array, you can read right off the end of your newly chosen size and it will look like garbage (1 trailing junk value & all zeroes...).

An array in C has two pieces, always. Start pointer, and size. Sometimes the size is implicit, but it needs to be there somehow, or you'll just keep reading forever.

If you need to return multiple things from a function, either:

- return (one or both) via a pointer parameter
- return them both through a struct

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  A simple enough problem, likely overlooked due to lack of sleep.  What would you suggest the best way to get both the array and size from the function would be?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your options.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up making a separate function basically just containing the loop under the comment "This loop is to count the number of elements between 0 and 9999".  This way, I would be able to find the size of a bucket (sans junk) without having to use the trim function.  Thanks again.